# How to remove specific part from a String in php

Tags: php, string

I have the following String
`Hi this string is to @removeStart be modified by @removeEnd function`

And I want to remove the string part coincides by `@removeStart` and `@removeEnd` and these two tags from the above string

Comment: lot of threads in SO,search

Comment: Atleast you could have showed your attempts and the expected output (still unclear)..

Comment: This is not a duplicate from that one, it is replacing some key word from the string but here I want to remove the string upto the end tag

Comment: Well seems like you didn't explain it clearly then :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$str = 'Hi this string is to @removeStart be modified by @removeEnd function';
echo preg_replace('/@removeStart (.*) @removeEnd/','',$str);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo Code Viper](http://codepad.viper-7.com/278Zjx)**</kbd>

#### Pattern [Check](http://www.regexr.com/38md2)

```
(@\b\w+)
```

#### PHP

```
<?php

    $str="Hi this string is to @removeStart be modified by @removeEnd function";

    echo preg_replace('(@\b\w+)','',$str);

?>
```

#### Result

```
Hi this string is to be modified by function
```